# Adding planetary symbols to a graph

Tags: text, special-characters

I am trying to add planetary symbols to a graph in R, while plotting planetary positions. Hershey seems to have those symbols embedded; e.g., demo(Hershey) gives the symbol \JU for the planetary symbol of Jupiter.

The problem is that I cannot add those symbols to the function text().

Any trick to make me move forward?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI  the answer I have found, as I am confident this will help some. The trick is to pass the symbol through the Unicode, instead of all of the babbling here and there. Here is an example for Jupiter

plot(9,9)

text(9, 9, , label="\u2643", pos=1)